# Display Checkbox Vertically in sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can any one help me to display Sharepoint2010 Checkbox Horizontally instead of default Vertical way in custom New form. I tried to use following script but no use.

```
<script src="/sites/IMOC/SiteAssets/Script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">

<script src="/sites/IMOC/SiteAssets/Script/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript">

$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
    columnName: "State:",
    perRow: 2
});</script>

Let me know if I made any mistake.
I also try the following.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function()
{
  var firstRadio = $j(".ms-RadioText:eq(0)");
  $j(".ms-RadioText:gt(0)").appendTo($j(firstRadio));
});
</script
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work I've used this function in the past, it is probably firing before the DOM is ready. Try wrapping the function in document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
      columnName: "State:",
      perRow: 2
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for update. I took Content Editor and add Script inside "Edit HTML Source Box" and try to run. Is this the correct approach or you suggest me to place it somewhere else. Also, jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js is the correct version for this

Comment: 1.4.2 is on the low end, for that version of SPServices, I believe Marc recommends a more recent version. A CEWP in 2010 is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Issue is resolved by using following script. var firstRadio = $("#Columnname table tbody tr td .ms-RadioText:eq(0)");
$("#Columnname table tbody tr td .ms-RadioText:gt(0)").appendTo($(firstRadio));